# C++ Unhandled exception after main.cpp returns and the executable wants to exit: location 0xfeeefef6

Tags: c++, com, unhandled-exception

I'm receiving the error message shown on the following figure. This error pops up at the very end of my C++ code when `main.cpp` goes beyond `return 0;` it means just when the executable wants to exit. I'm not sure why this error is happening. Does anybody know what the reason can be?

I'm using Microsoft COM classes in my C++ code. Maybe the error is due to the fact that these libraries are not unloaded after `return 0;`. Is there any command to unload all the loaded libraries (explicitly or implicitly) at the end of the `main.cpp`?

I have shown below my `main.cpp`. I think the error is because I don't use the `delete` after `new` inside my `main.cpp` I'm not sure.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have any global or local static variables? If so, are any of them an instance of a class you created? If so, what are you doing in the destructor?

Comment: It seems you are using a pointer that is in freed heap memory. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I showed my `main.cpp` on the question above can you please take a look at it.

Comment: @drescherjm I showed my `main.cpp` on the question above. Can you take a look at it?

Comment: I say the problem is not in your main.cpp. It's in your CMS class.

Comment: 0xfeeefeee is a magic number, it tells you that you are accessing memory that was allocated from the heap but was released.